# Converting a grayscale image to black and white

Tags: image, matlab, binary, converters, grayscale

I have a grayscale image that only has the values `60` and `117`. How can I convert the image to only `black` and `white` without graylevels?

I tried the `matlab` function `gray2ind`, but didn't get the expected output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try `im2bw(img, level)` with `level = 0.5`.

This is a matlab function that takes a grayscale image `img`, applies a threshold of `level` (a value between [0,1]) and returns a black and white image.

This function is part of the Image Processing Toolbox.  Your case is simple enough that you could also try something like:

```
bwImg = false(size(img));
bwImg(img == 117) = true;
```

I edited the above to set values equal to false/true to more closely mimic Matlab's `im2bw()` which returns a matrix of `logical` values rather than `ints`.

2nd Edit: Modified the code block to reflect improvements suggested by @Amro

Comment: Or use [`grathresh()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/graythresh.html) to determine `level`.

Comment: since the image has only two levels, you can simplify as: `bwImg = (img==117);`. btw initialize with `false(size(img))` instead of `zeros` to get logical matrix

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Can I extend that to 3,4,5,...etc values? My question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252146/converting-a-grayscale-image-to-black-and-white

Comment: You should be able to extend it to any number of values by changing `bwImg(img == 117) = true` to `bwImg(img > threshold) = true` for any value you choose for `threshold`.

Comment: @Ryan J. Smith. How would one choose the threshold? Is it empirical? Say we have three values for the pixels in an image: 17, 56, and 180. What may be a suitable threshold for that? Would it be suitable for instance to set the threshold as the maximum value between pixels? Thanks

Comment: The choice of threshold is completely dependent upon your intentions in converting an image to black and white to begin with.  In your example you really only have 2 meaningful values to threshold at (17, 56).  Thresholding below 17 or above 180 would result in an uninteresting image. In a broader application you might examine a histogram of your original pixel values via `hist(img)` to get a better idea for a threshold value.